# Proportional bounding boxes around centroid

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, r-sp, rgdal

I'd like to create proportional bounding boxes around a centroid regardless of the lat/lon of the centroid. I figured out how to make consistently proportional rectangle bounding boxes around a centroid by simply adding and subtracting a small number from the coordinates, and using a projection that preserves shape.

So now, the only problem is I don't want to use this projection, I want a projection that is more common and recognizable to the general public. If I use something like EPSG:4326, this method gives gives different shaped bounding boxes depending on the latitude. Is there a way to make a bounding box that doesn't rely on the coordinates, and is the same shape regardless of latitude?

```
#set parameters
city_name <- 'Paris'
zoom = .1

#get centroid to make box around
dat <- getbb(city_name, format_out ="data.frame", limit = 1) 
dat <- dat[,c("lat","lon")]
cols.num <- c("lat","lon")
dat[cols.num] <- sapply(dat[cols.num],as.numeric)

#make bounding box
my_box <- rgeos::bbox2SP(n = (dat$lat + zoom),
                         s = (dat$lat - zoom), 
                         w = (dat$lon + zoom), 
                         e = (dat$lon - zoom),
                         proj4string = CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))

plot(my_box)
```

Comment: So do you want a bounding box that is a fixed size (in metres) or a fixed shape (in degrees)? Clearly it can't be both.

Comment: @AllanCameron I want it to be a fixed shape, with the same proportions at any size. The size does not matter, I believe I can adjust dynamically with something like I have in my example code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a central cylindrical projection would do the trick, but as a warning, this comes with massive distortions move away from the equator. You can generally find the reference number for the projection systems here https://epsg.org/home.html, but I believe it is EPSG:4085.